# Note-taking software that is conducive to images?

Tags: lecture-notes, note-taking

Due to the lack of graphic tablets like iPad, I write my notes on paper, scan them, and keep them in obsidian. But I've realized that this is not the best way for some reasons:

- Exporting to PDF is dirty, the scanned page breaks a lot.

And in general, I don't find it very conducive to image-based notes. I write them and publish them to GitHub. If there's still something that I can do, I'd love to fix this issue.

I write a title of the topic that I am explaining, then post an image of it.

I'm doing this because unfortunately, I lost all my old notes made at my university. So, I am digitizing my notes as I've opportunity to re-study the computer science topics.

Any software?

Comment: One question is just how useful are any notes from last semester or earlier. You have the book (or a different text) to skim through if needed. Perhaps I was weird - the value in taking notes was in writing things down which helped set things in my brain. I never used my notes for studying from.

Comment: Good point raised. I believe it's useful. I have forgotten everything that I need to learn like I am a new uni student.

Comment: I get it. I need to go back and dig deeper into or relearn stuff, now some 40 years on. My notes from then would be useless. Reading a (different) text helps. Your learning/study style may differ. But you could just use your written notes like we did in the old days…